# Erro: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server

Estou tentando converter dados de uma coluna em NVARCHAR(255) para DECIMAL(10,2), porém, todas as formas que tentei sempre dá o mesmo erro **Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric**. Criei uma outra coluna do tipo DECIMAL(10,2) para transferir os dados da coluna do tipo NVARCHAR(255), mas mesmo com CONVERT ou CAST também não converte. Segue o código abaixo:

```
    SELECT CASE 
             WHEN Isnumeric(salario)  0 THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), 
                                             CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), salario)) 
             ELSE salario 
           END AS [SALÁRIO] 
    FROM dbo.rendimentos
```

Comment: Como está o formato dessa string no banco de dados? talvez esteja em um formato inválido para converter em decimal. Outra coisa. pode ser que esteja dando erro pois a coluna está null ou com string vazia.

Comment: A coluna salario está definida para permitir valores NULLs, mas não tem nenhum valor nulo. Usando a função ISNUMERIC(), todos os dados dessa coluna retornam o valor 1, ou seja, todos são numéricos. Mesmo assim retorna o erro de converção.

Comment: @KellySoares Qual é o separador de casa decimal: ponto ou vírgula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avalie a seguinte sugestão:

```
-- código #1  v2
SELECT salario,
       convert(decimal(10, 2), salario) as [SALÁRIO] 
  from dbo.rendimentos
  where Isnumeric(salario) = 1;
```

Entretanto, se os valores da coluna `salario` utilizem a vírgula como separador de casa decimal, o erro ocorre. Se for este o caso, o código correto é:

```
 -- código #2 v3
 SELECT salario,
        convert(decimal(10, 2), replace(salario, ',', '.')) as [SALÁRIO] 
  from dbo.rendimentos
  where Isnumeric(salario) = 1;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3f02a/1

Comment: Boa tarde José! O seu primeiro código ficou perfeito. Tinha uma tabela com mais de 20 mil registros e apenas 1 tinha vírgula para separar as casas decimais. Por causa dele todo o código estava dando problema e não havia percebido. Obrigada!